# What is the difference between numpy.where and numpy.argwhere for boolean inputs?

Tags: python, numpy

I am confused with the numpy.where and numpy.argwhere. For example,

```
 aa = (np.arange(10) + 5).reshape(2, -1)
```

If I run

```
 res = np.where(((aa == 7) | (aa == 8)))
```

Then

```
 >>> res
 (array([0, 0]), array([2, 3]))
```

If I run

```
 res2 = np.argwhere(((aa == 7) | (aa == 8)))
```

I get

```
 >>> res2
  array([[0, 2],
         [0, 3]])
```

Both numpy.where and numpy.argwhere give the coordinates of the nonzero elements in the boolean array. So if the inputs are boolean arrays, the two functions are basically doing the same thing. Is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [docs for `np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

> When only condition is provided, this function is a shorthand for np.asarray(condition).nonzero()

and nonzero returns a tuple of lists of indices *for each dimension* where the original array is non-zero (or false). `np.argwhere` on the other hand, returns a list of indices, that you can use to index into your original array. So in essence they are doing similar things, but to get the same output as `np.argwhere` from `np.where` you'd need to do:

`np.vstack(np.where(((aa == 7) | (aa == 8)))).T`

and the other way around:

```
a = np.argwhere(((aa == 7) | (aa == 8)))
tuple(a[:, i] for i in range(a.shape[1]))
```